# Find Jordan norm form of matrix using lambda-matrix techniques

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I can't transform this matrix of lambda-matrix techniques. I don't know this method, but I should use this method for solve. Eigenvalues equal to "-1". Guys, help me, please.

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 &1 &-1 \\ -3 &-4& 3 \\ -2 &-2& 1\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: What do you mean by lambda-matrix techniques? Are you saying finding the characteristic polynomial $$|A - \lambda I| = 0$$ or something else? Then, to find the generalized eigenvectors and the Jordan form?

Comment: @Moo I meant characteristic polynomial, but all transformations must be into this matrix and in the end must be get diagonal matrix (the last element is "-(λ+1)^3").

Comment: Well, this is a deficient matrix that is not diagonalizable, and there is triple eigenvalue, so the Jordan Form will be $$J = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$